# How to change the card column when it resize to mobile view?

Tags: css

I wanted to change my card view when it comes to mobile size, I want it to change to 2 column view. So based on my code how am I gonna do that?

From desktop size : https://pasteboard.co/I83IOBQ.png

Become like this: https://pasteboard.co/I83It0s.png

I change the flex length and grid size but still can't get the result that I want.

Latest Product

```
<v-divider></v-divider><br>
  <v-layout row wrap>

    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>First Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Second Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Third Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Fourth Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Fifth Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Sixth Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Sixth Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Sixth Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Sixth Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Sixth Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Sixth Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex style="width: 300px;">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>Sixth Card</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>


  </v-layout>
```

Result Must Be Like This : https://pasteboard.co/I83It0s.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [display helpers](http://%20https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/display). For example, `xs6 sm4 md3 lg3`, where the number after the helper indicates how many columns the element should possible occupy for each viewport size (there are 12 cols per row):

```
<v-flex xs6 sm4 md3 lg3>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-text>First Card</v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-flex>
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/b4e5zo1j/ ]

Comment: @Creativiousa https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work